# Haskell recursion in do block don't work (recursion is in list conprehension)

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm pretty new to Haskell, and want to execute recursion in do block.

```
countLines :: String -> IO Int
countLines filePath = do
    isFile <- doesFileExist filePath
    if isFile
        then do contents <- readFile filePath
                print contents
                pure 0
        else do files <- getDirectoryContents filePath    
                [countLines(file) | file <- files] -- recursion here!
                pure 0
```

until i add this list comprehension, everything works fine but once i add this, i get the following error:

```
Main.hs:59:17: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: IO (IO Int)
        Actual type: [IO Int]
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: [countLines (file) | file <- files]
      In the expression:
        do files <- getDirectoryContents filePath
           [countLines (file) | file <- files]
           pure 0
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        if isFile then
            do contents <- readFile filePath
               print contents
               pure 0
        else
            do files <- getDirectoryContents filePath
               [countLines (file) | file <- files]
               pure 0
   |
59 |                 [countLines(file) | file <- files]
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
bash-3.2$
```

does any one know how to fix this?

Comment: You can convert a list of actions (like `[ countFile(file) | file <- files ]`) into an action that executes them all using the `sequence` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list comprehension is an expression of the `[IO Int]`, not `IO Int`, while a list `[]` is a member of the `Monad` typeclass, it is not the one you are currently working with in the `do` block. You can use [**`mapM_ :: (Foldable f, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> f a -> m ()`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) to work with recursion here:

```
countLines :: String -> IO Int
countLines filePath = do
    isFile <- doesFileExist filePath
    if isFile
        then readFile filePath >>= print
        else getDirectoryContents filePath >>= mapM_ countLines
    pure 0
```

As [@chi says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544328/haskell-recursion-in-do-block-dont-work-recursion-is-in-list-conprehension/61544397#comment108867411_61544397), if you need to retrieve a list of the results, you should use [**`mapM :: (Traversable f, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM). This thus can you provide a list of the *results* of the monadic calls. You can for example sum these up to obtain the result. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I guess the OP actually wants `mapM` (or `traverse` / `for`) since they'll really need the returned `Int`s from the recursive calls.

Answer (score 2):

You're in the `IO` monad, so every line should produce an `IO a`, but your list comprehension produces... well, a list `[a]`. Thankfully, there is a function `sequence_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m ()`, that will turn your `[IO ()]` into a single `IO ()`, while running all of the IO actions in it. Thus your `else` block should look like this instead:

```
    else do files <- getDirectoryContents filePath    
            sequence_ [countLines(file) | file <- files]
            pure 0
```

As Willem mentions, it's possible to simplify these even more using `mapM_ :: (Foldable f, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> f a -> m ()`:

```
    else do files <- getDirectoryContents filePath    
            mapM_ countLines files
            pure 0
```